# SQL CONTAINS 'State of Ohi' doesn't return 'State of Ohio

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search, contains

I'm struggling to understand full text search & in particular contains. I have a table which contains these records.

```
NAME 
State Place
State of Ohio
State of Oh-debt
State of Ohio Highway
State of Ohio Office
State of Ohit
```

Everything comes back when searching..

```
SELECT t.Name FROM   tbl t  WHERE  CONTAINS (t.Name, '"State of"')
SELECT t.Name FROM   tbl t  WHERE  CONTAINS (t.Name, '"State of o"')
```

'State of Oh-debt' comes back when searching..

```
SELECT t.Name     FROM   tbl t    WHERE  CONTAINS (t.Name, '"State of oh"')
```

But when do

```
 SELECT t.Name 
    FROM   tbl t
    WHERE  CONTAINS (t.Name, '"State of ohi"')
```

nothing comes back.

I don't want to use LIKE '%%' because the potential number of records is large & would affect performance. Is they a way around this?

Comment: full text search ignores phrases that 50 percent of the data contains anyway. So if most of your test data contain that search string it is ignored

Comment: my tbl has 182818 records. 7 of them contain 'state of ohi' (used like '%state of ohi%' to check). sorry my example was just example of what I expect to be returned in my examples

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and `contain()` non-standard SQL) Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: See `<prefix_term>` for [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). There are also some examples near the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wildcards in a Contains Statement with a `*` like:

```
SELECT t.Name     FROM   tbl t    WHERE  CONTAINS (t.Name, '"State of ohi*"')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this can help?

```
select T.Name from  tbl t
where INSTR(upper(T.Name), 'STATE OF OHI', 1) > 0;

 --This is the correct sql server function
select T.Name from  tbl t
where CHARINDEX(upper(T.Name), 'STATE OF OHI', 1) > 0;
```

Comment: instr isnt a sql server function?

Comment: At the time, there was no sql-srver TAG as you can see from the edit that was made. Thanks for the edit of my answer.

Comment: A downside to that approach is that it can't use an index lookup. At best it might use an index scan.